# Node.js API needs to click to fetch JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to use a joke API and Rest country API. I made 2 async functions, but when I use the country API I need to click the submit button twice before the country flag and coat of arms images loads. The joke api retrieves the data right away.

```
app.post("/", urlEncodedParser, (req, res) => {
    sendJokeRequest();
    let countryName = req.body.country;
    console.log(countryName);
    sendCountryRequest(countryName);
    res.render("api-page", {
        data: req.body.country,
        joke: joke,
        countryFlag: countryFlag,
        countryCoatOfArms: countryCoatOfArms
    });         
});
var joke;
var countryFlag, countryCoatOfArms

const sendJokeRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        console.log(response.data.value)
        joke = response.data.value;
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
const sendCountryRequest = async (country) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}?fullText=true`);
        console.log(response.data[0]);
        countryFlag = response.data[0].flags.svg;
        countryCoatOfArms = response.data[0].coatOfArms.svg;
    
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: I am using PUG in the front end and it loads properly. Could it be with the api? I am using await and async so it fetches the data before it renders the page? Is the back-end code fine?

Comment: The submit button is on the PUG page. But it loads the joke statement when you click submit, it just takes 2 clicks to show the country images

Comment: You should probably await `sendJokeRequest();` and `sendCountryRequest(countryName);`. Please add some debugging details.

Comment: since `sendJokeRequest` and `sendCountryRequest` are `async` you are executing `res.render(...` before they have retrieved any data at all - and using "globals" for `joke`, `countryFlag` and `countryCoatOfArms` is a very poor design - they should be returned from `sendJokeRequest` and `sendCountryRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `sendJokeRequest` and `sendCountryRequest` are `async` you are executing `res.render(...` before they have retrieved any data at all - and using "globals" for `joke`, `countryFlag` and `countryCoatOfArms` is a very poor design - they should be returned from `sendJokeRequest` and `sendCountryRequest`

This should work

```
app.post("/", urlEncodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const joke = await sendJokeRequest();
        const countryName = req.body.country;
        console.log(countryName);
        const {countryFlag, countryCoatOfArms} = await sendCountryRequest(countryName);
        res.render("api-page", {
            data: req.body.country,
            joke,
            countryFlag,
            countryCoatOfArms
        });
    } catch(err) {
        // handle errors here in one place
    }
});

const sendJokeRequest = async() => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
    console.log(response.data.value)
    return response.data.value;
};

const sendCountryRequest = async(country) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}?fullText=true`);
    console.log(response.data[0]);
    countryFlag = response.data[0].flags.svg;
    countryCoatOfArms = response.data[0].coatOfArms.svg;
    return {countryFlag, countryCoatOfArms};
}
```